# Deploy AD server over VPN

Tags: active-directory, vpn

I have recently been tasked with finding a way to have centralized account management for workstations that are used remotely. An AD server is thus far my only solution to managing machine accounts for our users, however users would have to connect to our VPN before authenticating to an AD server. Is such a thing possible (to connect to VPN first, then authenticate with AD server over internet), or is there a better solution to this problem? We currently employ a RADIUS server to authenticate our VPN users as well as for internal systems, and an AD server would only serve to ensure that user accounts on machines enforce proper password controls etc. Can anyone advise the best course of action?

Comment: Pre-Logon VPN or DirectAccess would both work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? At this point, my only option is to deploy the AD server within our VPN and have folks authenticate

Comment: You stated: `however users would have to connect to our VPN before authenticating to an AD server. Is such a thing possible (to connect to VPN first, then authenticate with AD server over internet), or is there a better solution to this problem?` - Yes, it is possible with a VPN that supports pre-login connections. Another possibility is to use DirectAccess.